# Flash : Any tutorial to build Simple Facebook Game

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I am independent developer ,developed an iphone game.I am interested to build an basic flash game For facebook.I am in mac and i got Adobe cs5.I am really noob in flash.I googled and it did not help me.Please some one guide me.